# How to assign an operation to a complex number during the declaration?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, complex-numbers

I'm writing a class for complex numbers and when I declare one of those, I must declare it before and only after  I can assign to it an operation.

---

For example:

**This works**:

```
ComplexNumber Number;  
Number = AnotherComplex + (or -) AgainAnotherComplex;
```

---

**This doesn't work**:

```
ComplexNumber Number = AnotherComplex + (or -) AgainAnotherComplex;
```

---

**I leave here is the .h file**:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_NUMBERS_H_INCLUDED
#define COMPLEX_NUMBERS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream> // for std namespace

class ComplexNumber
{
    public:
        ComplexNumber();
        ComplexNumber(float RealPart, float ImaginaryPart);
        ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber &NewComplexNumber);
        ~ComplexNumber();
        void SetRealPart(float RealPart);
        void SetImaginaryPart(float ImaginaryPart);
        friend ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber Complex1, const ComplexNumber Complex2);
        friend ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber Complex1, const ComplexNumber Complex2);
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &output, const ComplexNumber &NumberToDsiplay);
        friend std::istream & operator >>(std::istream &input, ComplexNumber &NumberToInput);
        bool operator==(const ComplexNumber Complex);
        bool operator!=(const ComplexNumber Complex);

    private:
        float RealPart;
        float ImaginaryPart;
};

#endif // COMPLEX_NUMBERS_H_INCLUDED
```

**And I also leave here the .cpp file**:

```
#include "Complex Numbers.h"

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber()
{
    RealPart = 0;
    ImaginaryPart = 0;
}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(float RealPart, float ImaginaryPart)
{
    SetRealPart(RealPart);
    SetImaginaryPart(ImaginaryPart);
}

ComplexNumber::~ComplexNumber()
{
}

ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber &NewComplexNumber)
{
    RealPart = NewComplexNumber.RealPart;
    ImaginaryPart = NewComplexNumber.ImaginaryPart;
}

void ComplexNumber::SetRealPart(float RealPart)
{
    this->RealPart=RealPart;
}

void ComplexNumber::SetImaginaryPart(float ImaginaryPart)
{
    this->ImaginaryPart=ImaginaryPart;
}

ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber Complex1, const ComplexNumber Complex2)
{
    ComplexNumber TemporaryComplexNumber;
    TemporaryComplexNumber.RealPart = Complex1.RealPart + Complex2.RealPart;
    TemporaryComplexNumber.ImaginaryPart = Complex1.ImaginaryPart + Complex2.ImaginaryPart;

    return TemporaryComplexNumber;
}

ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber Complex1, const ComplexNumber Complex2)
{
    ComplexNumber TemporaryComplexNumber;
    TemporaryComplexNumber.RealPart = Complex1.RealPart - Complex2.RealPart;
    TemporaryComplexNumber.ImaginaryPart = Complex1.ImaginaryPart - Complex2.ImaginaryPart;

    return TemporaryComplexNumber;
}


std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &output, const ComplexNumber &NumberToDsiplay)
{
    if(NumberToDsiplay.ImaginaryPart > 0)
        output << std::endl << NumberToDsiplay.RealPart << "+" << NumberToDsiplay.ImaginaryPart << "i";
    else if(NumberToDsiplay.ImaginaryPart < 0)
        output << std::endl << NumberToDsiplay.RealPart << "" << NumberToDsiplay.ImaginaryPart << "i";
    else if(NumberToDsiplay.ImaginaryPart == 0)
        output << std::endl << NumberToDsiplay.RealPart << "  (The imaginary part is equal to 0)";
    return output;
}

std::istream & operator >>(std::istream &input, ComplexNumber &NumberToInput)
{
    std::cout << "Enter the real part: ";
    input >> NumberToInput.RealPart;
    std::cout << "Enter the imaginary part: ";
    input >> NumberToInput.ImaginaryPart;
}

bool ComplexNumber::operator==(const ComplexNumber Complex)
{
    return RealPart==Complex.RealPart && ImaginaryPart==Complex.ImaginaryPart;
}

bool ComplexNumber::operator!=(const ComplexNumber Complex)
{
    if(RealPart != Complex.RealPart && ImaginaryPart != Complex.ImaginaryPart)
            return true;
    else if(RealPart != Complex.RealPart && (!(ImaginaryPart != Complex.ImaginaryPart)))
            return true;
    else if(ImaginaryPart != Complex.ImaginaryPart && (!(RealPart != Complex.RealPart)))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note: you could just use `std::complex<float>`. `This doesn't work:` - how do you detect the "doesn't work" state? Does it compile? Any warnings? Errors? Does it throw an exception? The result is different that what you expect? Most probably you lack `ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber& NewComplexNumber);` constructor.

Comment: Do you really have a space in your header filename (`"Complex Numbers.h"`)?

Comment: `const` is missing in copy ctor and default one will do the job.

Comment: I add the const keyword and now it works, thanks @KamilCuk

Comment: A more convenient implementation of `operator!=` is `return !(*this == Complex);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare the copy constructor like

```
ComplexNumber( const ComplexNumber &NewComplexNumber);
               ^^^^^
```

Otherwise the compiler can not bind a non-constant reference to a temporary that is the result of the expression

```
AnotherComplex + (or -) AgainAnotherComplex
```

that invokes either of the operators

```
    friend ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber Complex1, const ComplexNumber Complex2);
    friend ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber Complex1, const ComplexNumber Complex2);
```

that in turn should be declared like

```
    friend ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber &Complex1, const ComplexNumber &Complex2);
    friend ComplexNumber operator-(const ComplexNumber &Complex1, const ComplexNumber &Complex2);
```

that is the parameters should be referenced types.

And this operator definition

```
bool ComplexNumber::operator!=(const ComplexNumber Complex)
{
    if(RealPart != Complex.RealPart && ImaginaryPart != Complex.ImaginaryPart)
            return true;
    else if(RealPart != Complex.RealPart && (!(ImaginaryPart != Complex.ImaginaryPart)))
            return true;
    else if(ImaginaryPart != Complex.ImaginaryPart && (!(RealPart != Complex.RealPart)))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

does not make great sense.

Define it like

```
bool ComplexNumber::operator!=(const ComplexNumber &Complex) const
{
    return not( *this == Complex );
}
```

Pay attention to the qualifier `const` after the parameter list. The same qualifier you need to add to the `operator ==`.

Comment: I've rarely seen `friend ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber& Complex1, const ComplexNumber& Complex2);` being used as members in classes. The more prevalent tends to be `ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber& complex2) const;`. I wonder if there's any benefit in using the former, i.e. friending operator+?

Comment: @TrebledJ Usually binary operators are declared like a friend function to allow implicit conversions.

Comment: Ah, that's sweet. Good to know. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The `=` in declarations is not assignment.

```
ComplexNumber a = b + c;
```

is just another way to write

```
ComplexNumber a(b + c);
```

I.e. it initializes `a` from `b + c` by invoking the copy constructor.

Your copy constructor is declared as

```
    ComplexNumber(ComplexNumber &NewComplexNumber);
```

It takes its argument by reference. References can't bind to temporary values such as the result of expressions (e.g. `a + b`, `a - b`).

Fix:

```
    ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber &NewComplexNumber);
```

As a rule of thumb, a copy constructor should always take its argument by const reference.

Answer (score 3):

Add a const copy constructor:

`ComplexNumber::ComplexNumber(const ComplexNumber & NewComplexNumber)`

The line `ComplexNumber Number = a + b;` calls the copy constructor of the class. However, the result of `a + b` is an r-value, and the only copy constructor you provide only takes an l-value.